# Rust unnecessary memory copy?

Tags: rust

In order to implement a iterator for a struct that has a slice with a lifetime, I had to do

```
struct S<'a, T> {
    inner: &'a mut [T],
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for S<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let temp = std::mem::take(&mut self.inner);
        let (first, rest) = temp.split_first_mut()?;
        self.inner = rest;
        Some(first)
    }
}
```

While writing this code, i realized lifetime enforces additional memory copy(mem::take) that would be unnecessary in C or C++. Am i missing something here or is this a small price that rust pays for the lifetime?

Comment: What analogous C++ code are you imagining that doesn't copy `inner`? (Bearing in mind `inner` is *just a reference*, not the data)

Comment: @trentcl: `std::slice::IterMut` avoids creating a temporary, but it uses raw pointers and unsafe operations instead... @pandawithcat, why not make `inner` an instance of that, and just delegate to it?

Comment: why don't you use some sort of... index ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e576c12864425b79f6cd18a73827d97

Answer (score 1):

1. Unnecessary copies are to be optimized by LLVM.
2. `mem::take<T>` requires that `T` `impl`s `Default` so do not regard it as a generic solution.